# ACF relationship field display on Search & Filter Pro plugin

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm trying to show a relationship field in the Search & Filter Pro results.php page.

I'm trying to call it with  but I only get the id of the post related.

I've tryed another approach but it posts the title of the page, not the related one.

If I try to get it this way it post the id again

Is there any way I can show the title instead?